# Which queue to use in GCD

Tags: objective-c

I'm using this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

//saving stuff to NSUserDefaults

});
```

It works as long as the code is not called twice in rapid succession, at which point I get a crash. All it says is `Thread 7: trace` for the crash, in a screen for `CFRetain`.

I'm guessing that my queue should not allow a restart of this routine unless it has finished. But I'm not sure which of the many parameters to change. I do not need it to be high priority, nor am I sure it needs to be the global queue, and to be honest thread programming requires some time for me to nail all this down, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just a guess, try calling different queue types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this operation to run asynchronously but always on the same queue (meaning : it's done in background but never twice at the same time), I recommend you create a `dispatch_queue_t` in your class  (or *somewhere accessible globally*, outside the method) :

That would go like :

```
@interface Foo : Bar {

    @private
    dispatch_queue_t _savingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("savingQueue", NULL);

}

-(void)saveStuff;

@end
```

and save always on that queue

```
-(void)saveStuff{

    dispatch_async(_savingQueue, ^{

    //saving stuff to NSUserDefaults

    });

}
```

Comment: this makes sense except that your `dispatch_queue_create` should specify that it is a serial queue if you don't want to run the task twice at the same time, right? You have passed `NULL` which would not be the best choice I think.

Comment: i see now that NULL results in the default, which is indeed serial. many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The global queues are *inherently concurrent*.  When you `dispatch_sync()` to these queues, it merely means that the function will return when the block is done executing.  It does *not* guarantee that blocks on that queue won't be running concurrently.

Create serial queue (`dispatch_queue_create()` with the serial option) and dispatch your blocks onto it.  Be careful to not `disptch_sync()` onto the queue from a block running in that queue;  deadlock ensues.

Comment: of the various Apple docs on threaded programming, what is the best to read do you think, or another resource?

Comment: I would start here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html  Then branch out to the technology specific notes or guides.